# php Curl - couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, nginx, curl

Добрый день, коллеги!

Возникла следующая проблема. Пытаемся получить маркеры доступа oauth с помощью curl по https. На нашем сервере - всё отлично. У заказчика же возникает проблема - curl ничего не возвращает. Вот пример кода:

```
    $myCurl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);        
    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'));
    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    $verbose = fopen('curlLog.txt', 'a+');
    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
```

В логе curlLog.txt отображается следующее:

> - About to connect() to esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru port 443 (#0)
> - Trying 213.59.255.177... * Connection refused
> - couldn't connect to host
> - Closing connection #0

Судя по phpinfo и на нашем сервере и на сервере заказчика - всё совершенно одинаковое. За исключением одного компонента в составе curl.

У нас `SSL Version - NSS/3.15.3` и всё работает. 
У заказчика `SSL Version - NSS/3.14.0.0`
на обоих серверах php 5.5.0beta2 
Работает это всё под nginx.

Может ли это быть из-за NSS? И да - заказчик сказал, что прокси нет, и ничто не не должно блокировать доступ.

---

Так же выяснилось, что если из терминала вызывать

```
curl -v https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/aas/oauth2/
```

то у заказчика та же ошибка.

Comment: *всё совершенно одинаковое* — и даже ip-адрес? по-моему, по поводу *connection refused* вам лучше обратиться не на этот сайт, а в техподдержку сайта gosuslugi.ru.

Comment: Работает как на сервере компании у нас, так и на продакшн сервере заказчика. Не работает у них только на тестовой площадке.

Comment: вот я бы и написал об этом в упомянутую техподдержку. а здесь мы можем только гадать на кофейной гуще, почему же это сайт сбрасвыет соединение при обращении с одного из ваших серверов.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще проблемы с соединением из вне нет, ищите проблему в коде.

```
curl https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru -I
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 27 Apr 2016 17:20:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/profile/user

>
```

Вотзапрос через рандомную проксю и тоже отдает нормально , попробуйте проксировать мб у зака на серваке фаервол вашу маску фильтрует:

```
curl 'https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru' --proxy http://217.196.160.83:3128 -I
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 07:16:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/profile/user
```

Попробовал Ваш код 1-1 и все ок =( 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выяснили, что когда заказчик использует curl из терминала - та же ошибка.

Comment: `curl 'https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru' --proxy http://217.196.160.83:3128 -I<br/>
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established<br/>
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently<br/>
Server: nginx<br/>
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 07:16:07 GMT<br/>
Content-Type: text/html<br/>
Content-Length: 178<br/>
Connection: keep-alive<br/>
Location: https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/profile/user<br/>` вот запрос через рандомную проксю тоже все отдает нормально

Comment: Думаю, попробовать у заказчика обновить curl. Других вариантов не вижу. У меня на машине тоже запрос проходит.